# Extract a column from text file - Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner py.

I need to extract the contents of column 12 from a huge flat text file every time a certain word is found within the text file (similar to `awk '{print $12}'` in Bash) in a Python script.

So far I have (example, not real code):

```
word = a_word
for a_word in data:
   column12 = data.split()
   print(column12[11])
```

I assumed that I should start counting from 0 as opposed to 1, though I very well may be incorrect.

Also, is a `for` loop correct for this type of code?

Thanks!

Comment: What format is your data in?  Could you post a row or two of sample data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop over the open file object:

```
with open('somefile') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line.split()[11])
```

So, yes, use a `for` loop and use 0-based indexing.

Comment: if we need to split 2 columns ? I tried `print(line.split()[1][2])` It says `print(line.split()[0][1])
IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: @SitzBlogz: `str.split()` returns a list object. If you need two columns from that, then assign the output of `line.split()` to a variable, and pick out the two elements you wanted from that list.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are text files with delimiter (i.e. space or comma) separated values, you might want to look into python's csv module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Fields in csv files can be separated by delimiters other than comma, so that not a requirement. So, I agree using it should be considered.